# How can I get a collection of activities in a specified tag like 'funny'

Tags: google-plus

I'd like using google plus HTTP REST API to get a collection of a specified tag like 'funny' or 'music' or 'sport' or ... How can I do it?

I'm using API KEY to get so it is no need to use the OAuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the [activities.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) method.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?query=%23funny&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```